# Is it a same origin policy violation to manipulate image data you retrieved from another site using PHP and cURL?

Tags: php, html, curl, canvas, same-origin-policy

I was wondering if same origin policy is violated if you retrieve an image using PHP and cURL and manipulate it using HTML5 canvas?  I know getImageData and putImageData doesn't work for images fetched from different (sub)domains.  I am not too familiar with the cURL library but I hear that the output that you fetch can either be immediately echoed in the browser or you can put it to the server for later use.  With the immediate output method, does the same origin policy still prevent me from manipulating the remote image data on my local machine however I want?

In the end, what I intend to do is use a CDN to store images and have a web server retrieve them  and manipulate them (using canvas) upon client request.

Curl seems easy and I'll take the time to learn it if anyone has any experience on the subject.

Do you think hosting the images on the CDN in base64 and translating on the server is a pratical idea?  I'm just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by hosting the images as base64?

Answer (score 2):

Provided the PHP script you use is in the same domain... If you retrieve an object from a remote server and deliver it down to a client connected to your server, from the client's perspective it does indeed come from your server, hence it is not a same-origin violation.  This is true whether you retrieve it with cURL and immediately dump it down to the client browser, or if you hang onto it in memory, modify it, and then dump it down to the browser.